# Unable to Connect Postgre which is on Dockers Container with Talend

Tags: postgresql, docker, networking, docker-compose, talend

I am trying to connect Postgre DB which is hosted on linux container to Talend ETL tool which is on my host windows machine, but unable to do so.

[My Postgre credentials which are successfully connecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkbSI.png)

[Talend Snapshot which popups connectivity issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omNlf.png)

Well, I have tried every thing to connect, also did docker inspect [container] to verify IP address.

[I also tried to ping the container from host system but it is giving me timeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqYUv.png)

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

99% of the time, timeouts are caused by a firewall blocking communication. You need to open the network path to port 5432. This is not a PostgreSQL issue.

Comment: I have disabled the firewall but still the same issue.

Comment: @HassaanAbedi I'm not familiar with your infrastructure but it's not always the DB host's firewall. You're welcome to explain more about your network topology.